# Web service call returns 405 method not allowed error

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-405, wcf-4

I currently have a deployed wcf application on iis 7.5, windows server 2008 R2.  I am using a asp 4.0 mvc which calls the different methods of the wcf web service application.

When I make an ajax GET request to any method in the wcf application I get the expected json result and all works fine.  However, when I make a POST request I get the 405 method not allowed error.

I checked the "Handle Mappings" in iis and all the .svc mappings allow ALL Verbs.
 1. My svc-ISAPI is mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll.

1. My svc-Integrated is mapped to "System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

All the mappings seem to be correct.

I am not sure why my POST will not work.

thanks,
Matt

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue? I am having an identical problem on a production server and nearly at the point of rebuilding it!

Comment: i did resolve this issue.  I believe it had something to do with our jquery ajax call using jsonp.  If we changed to just json the post then worked.